# What are the disadvantages of using a StringBuilder?

Tags: string, .net-4.0, stringbuilder

I know that StringBuilder is more efficient than a normal string when processing code which modifies the string value a lot because although strings act like value types, they are actually reference, which makes them immutable so every time we change it, we need to create a new reference in memory.

My question is that, why doesn't .NET just use stringBuilder by default? There must be some disadvantages of it over just using String. Can anyone tell me what they are?

The only thing I can think of is perhaps it is a heavier object and it takes more time to instantiate so if you aren't changing the string too much, this would override the benefits of StringBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are made immutable in order to be manipulated in a thread safe way. Because StringBuilder is mutable it is not thread safe. In addition you can make "copies" of a string by copying the references to the string rather than making a whole new object. Mutable objects can be changed via any of their references making this dangerous.

Comment: @Diego Sevilla The OP is wondering why use immutable String over mutable StringBuilder. Thread safety is one of the reasons.

Comment: Seems okay. Thread safety is something to be aware of. Using StringBuilder by default would reverse it from "opt in" mutability to "opt out" mutability.

Comment: @Diego: This would apply if you were passing around a string builder, rather than passing around strings.

Comment: What I mean is that the design choice in this case is not driven by the thread-safety, but for efficiency, that is for sure. Thread-safety may be a side effect of immutable strings, but (IMHO) not the driving design decision for `String`s to be immutable.

Comment: @Merlyn: But why would you think of passing `StringBuilder`s? Note the name! :) It is just for building them...

Comment: @Diego: For the same reason you might pass around strings and build upon them in a multi-threaded app.  Maybe you have textual data that isn't order specific, but is expensive to generate.  In which case, you're basically using a `StringBuilder` as an "optimized" `List<string>` or `string`.  But as Vincent said, it won't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a not so nice pattern (having to create another object *and then* using the `toString()` method to actually get the `String`). Note also that as the `+` operator for `String`s is special, the compiler can internally optimize the string copies, so maybe in .NET there is no practical overhead.

Comment: So using StringBuilder for simple string stuff may actually use more ram and cpu time. The MS docu on StringBuilder points out when to use String instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder. +1